# Prove $\left(A\times A\right)\setminus \left(B\times B\right)=\left(A\setminus B\right)\times \left(A\setminus B\right)$ or find a counterexample.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Definition of Cartesian product:

$A×B=\left\{\left(x,\:y\right):\:x\:∈\:A\:and\:y\:∈\:B\right\}$

---

1. Let $x, y\in \left(A\times A\right)\setminus \left(B\times B\right)$

= $x\in  A\times A$ and $y\notin  B \times B$

= ($x\in  A$ and  $x\in  A$) and ($y\notin B$ and $y\notin B$)

= $x\in  A$ and $y\notin B$

---

2. Let $x, y\in$ $\left(A\setminus B\right)\times \left(A\setminus B\right)$

= ($x\in A$ and $y\notin B$) and ($x\in A$ and $y\notin B$)

= $x\in  A$ and $y\notin B$

---

Therefore, $\left(A\times A\right)\setminus \left(B\times B\right)=\left(A\setminus B\right)\times \left(A\setminus B\right)$ as needed.

**I'm not sure about this solution, any feedback would be appreciated.**

Comment: This is wrong, $x \in A \times A$ doesn't mean that $x \in A$ and $x \in A$. It means that there are $a_1$ and $a_2$ in $A$ such that $x = (a_1,a_2)$.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. Why $x\in A\times A \Rightarrow x\in A \vee x\in A$? It is equivalent with $A\times A\subseteq A$, somhow nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not true. $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{1\}$. Then $(A\times A)\setminus (B\times B)$ consists of $3$ elements while $(A\setminus B)\times (A\setminus B)$ consists of one element.

Comment: Can you please explain how $\left(A\times \:A\right) ∖ \left(B\times B\right)$ will consist of 3 elements?

Comment: That is because $A\times A$ has $4=2\cdot 2$ elements and $B\times B$ has $1=1\cdot 1$ element, $4-1=3$.